# How to properly use CSS content?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with this piece of code. It keeps showing up as the letter "a" instead of the mobile menu symbol.

[image]

```css
.mobile_menu_bar:before {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 32px;
  content: "\61";
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="et_mobile_nav_menu">
  <div class="mobile_nav closed">
    <span class="select_page">Select Page</span>
    <span class="mobile_menu_bar mobile_menu_bar_toggle"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Am I suppose to define the content: "\61" ?

Comment: 61 is code for a. Are you using a different font?

Comment: I'm trying to replicate a word press page because I dont have access to the FTP so I just grabbed everything from the source code and only thing throwing things off are these letters which are showing up on the mobile menu's and buttons. CSS is not my thing. I'm more of a php and javascript guy

Answer (score 0):

`22` was lost in action. It should be `\2261`. See the snippet below:

```css
.mobile_menu_bar:before {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 32px;
  content: "\2261";
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="et_mobile_nav_menu">
  <div class="mobile_nav closed">
    <span class="select_page">Select Page</span>
    <span class="mobile_menu_bar mobile_menu_bar_toggle"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello may u forget some code, try like this

```
.mobile_menu_bar:before{
position: relative;
top: 0;
left: 0;
font-size: 32px;
content: "\2261";
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Html file:

```
<div id="et_mobile_nav_menu">
  <div class="mobile_nav closed">
    <span class="select_page">Select Page</span>
    <span class="mobile_menu_bar mobile_menu_bar_toggle"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```